# iOS detect if public wi-fi is redirecting to another URL

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wifi, redirect

I'm developing a really simple app that has a single webView that has to open a certain mobile version of the site. Here's the trick, many public wi-fi's here redirect you to their own  little page where they ask you to login and stuff. I need to detect that and show "no connection" alert, and this login screen should not be seen. I've tried to do this in webView delegate method

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {

if (![inRequest.URL.absoluteString containsString:@"mySite.com"]) {

    //no connection code

    return NO;

}

return YES;

}
```

It doesn't work, login screen still shows up. Is this the way to do what I need or I have to look somwhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the system is doing a redirect and feeding you back different data. This will usually have a different `mainDocumentURL` unless they're doing some really sneaky trickery in their router.

By detecting a different `mainDocumentURL` than the one you originally tried to load, you could intercept the behaviour and mess up things.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
  NSString *loadingURL = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
  if (![loadingURL isEqualToString:requestedURL]) {
    webView.hidden = YES;
    // Show message.
  }
}
```